# Hide Checked Checkbox when Unchecked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, hide

I have a checkbox a label, with a textfield on one line.

When page loads the checkbox is CHECKED, if a user UNCHECKED the checkbox, I want the line to be removed. Not really a show/hide as I dont need to redisplay the unchecked checkbox.

Is there a quick way to do this? I am using JQuery to add rows, but if unchecked, I want to row to be removed. I am using append, so I guess I want to 'prepend' or 'remove' added checkbox and line.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
$("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
});

$("#btn2").click(function(){
$("ul").append("<li><input type='checkbox' checked> Other Group 
&nbsp;<select><option>(HG) 1</option><option>(OG) 2</option>
<option>(OG) 3</option><option>(OG) 4</option><option>(OG) 
5</option></select> &nbsp;  <input type='text' name='fname' 
size='30'></li>");
});
});
</script>
```

HTML

Other Groups

Selected

```
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" 
value="Bike" checked>
<label for="vehicle1"> Rock Quarry Worker</label></li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<style>
ul {

padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}
</style>

<p>Availble </p>
<form>
    <style>
        .space {li {
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}}
    </style>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle0" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" 
class="space"> <label for="vehicle1"> Row Boat Operator</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car" 
class="space">
<label for="vehicle2"> Window Washer</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
<label for="vehicle3"> Zoo Keeper</label><br></form>
<p><button id="btn2" class="btn2">+</button> Add </p>


<p>&nbsp;</p>



<style>
    .btn2 {
        background-color: red;
        color:#FFF;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-family:Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic 
Bold", "Arial Black", "sans-serif";

        padding: 6px;

    }
</style>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML, as well as the code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `removeChild(yourCheckbox)` to remove your checkbox